# Reverse a pull from VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have mistakenly taken the pull from wrong branch. How to revert it from VSCODE ?

I need to revert the changes to the previous state which it was before the pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git rebase --abort
```

This will take you before the pull stage.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, as of my knowledge, there isn't any built-in feature that lets you revert a pull.

Although, you could do something like

```
git checkout [revision] .
```

where `[revision]` is the hash of the commit you had previously.

**Note: don't forget the `.` at the end ;)**

Comment: `git reset` will let you do anything you want to the current branch state. Regardless, OP seems to be asking for GUI help with VS Code.